# C#. Оптимизация PLINQ через Partitioner

Tags: c#, plinq

хочу сделать проекцию (Select) 100000 элементов параллельно, с сохранением последовательности.

```
   var nums1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 100000).ToArray();
   var particioner = Partitioner.Create(nums1, true);
   var points= particioner.AsParallel()
        .AsOrdered()
        .Select(i =>
        {
            //Задержки для проверки AsOrdered(). сохранение порядка элементов при длительной обработке некоторых элементов.
            if (i == 1) Thread.Sleep(100);
            if (i == 5) Thread.Sleep(2000);
            if (i == 6) Thread.Sleep(3000);

            return new Point {X = i};
        })
        .ToArray();
```

Чтобы не порождать много новых потоков для быстрой операции проекции к объекту Point, я думаю нужно использовать Partitioner.
Самое простое - использовать его в автоматическом режиме, вызвав на нем AsParallel().
Оптимально ли такое решение или лучше использовать ручное разбиение на порции.
И потом упорядочить коллекцию?

```
Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, nums1.Length), range => {
   for (var i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++) {
      var elem= nums1[i] 
      points[i] = new Point {X = elem};
   }
});
```

И стоит ли использовать
WithDegreeOfParallelism() для тонкой настройки?

Comment: `WithDegreeOfParallelism()` стоит использовать, если количество одновременно создаваемых потоков сильно больше, чем `Environment.ProcessorsCount * 2`. А так, замеряйте общую производительность, смотрите количество создаваемых потоков. Если разница будет большая - ответ станет очевидным.

Comment: Спасибо, померю BenchmarkDotNet.

Comment: Для показанного кода явно быстрее будет второй вариант. Всё зависит от длительности (тяжести) обработки одного элемента массива. [How to: Speed Up Small Loop Bodies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-speed-up-small-loop-bodies) - наверняка вы это видели.

Comment: А вообще. сто тысяч элементов и, соответственно, сто тысяч итераций - это очень мало по современным меркам. Не исключено, что пройтись по массиву такого размера без распараллеливания будет быстрее, чем запускать потоки. Опять же, зависит от тяжести операции, выполняемой на каждой итерации. `points[i] = new Point { X = nums1[i] }` - это очень лёгкая операция. Поэтому один поток рулит.

Comment: Да, надо несколько вариантов проверить и сравнить с последовательной обработкой. Если из вашего опыта исходить использование Partitioner.Create(nums1, true).AsParallel() работает в большинстве случаев оптимально? И по какому алгоритму там определяется размер батча для обработки, не нашел в описании этого. И если Partitioner.Create вообще не вызывать, вряд ли будет попытка создать 10000 одновременных задач на выполнение.